# How to resolve a class in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-manifest

I am working on a project that uses camera. In the AndroidManifest.xml, I am getting "Cannot resolve class uses-permission" and upon inspection I get "Inspection info: This inspection highlights unresolvable XML tag references in Android resource file." I get this error in almost every tag that I use such as, application, manifest, uses-feature and intent-filter tags.

I have tried reinstalling and restarting the studio, invalidating cache and restarting, syncing with gradle, creating new project but nothing worked.

here is the full code for the xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="edu.stanford.ee368.viewfinderee368">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA"/>
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".ViewfinderEE368"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please let me know how to resolve this error and what does this sort of error mean.

Comment: sorry about that, i removed the android studio tag as a habit but in this case it might actually be relevant, putting your question back to how it was originally, i tried this manifest file and i don't seem to have any issues myself from what i can tell, so might just be related to your android studio ? i'm not sure

Comment: Thank you :) Please let me know if you have any idea of what is error actually means. I have some deadlines coming soon :p

Comment: `I get this error in almost every tag that I use such as, application, manifest, uses-feature and intent-filter tags` this sounds like a bigger issue, like i said copying that manifest doesn't seem to give any issues, might be something wrong elsewhere

Comment: hmm I see.  Since, this is a bigger problem and getting a single solution may not be possible I tried uninstalling the studio. However, this happens even after uninstalling the whole android studio. Am I not uninstalling correctly (I am using IOBituninstaller) Like is there any registry files that I need to manually delete so that after reinstalling, the software is completely fresh and its less likely to get the error back? Or maybe its gridle issue, although gradle sync is successful. Feel like uninstalling is the only option remaining.

Comment: no idea, so even creating a blank project from the templates android studio provides also gives you errors ?

Comment: Yes :( Are you using Android Studio Bumblebee latest version too?

Comment: When you use these tags, are they imported in the MainActivity.java file? like import android.Manifest ?

Comment: Have you opened the app's manifest or the build manifest? The build manifest gives these errors. You should ignore them